# How does React's key help when a lot of nodes in DOM is reversed

Tags: reactjs

I was reading this article https://medium.com/technogise/dom-manipulation-in-browser-59b793bee559 to understand why it is expensive to manipulate DOM directly, but I still get confused about why React's key properties can help in certain scenarios.

when we do:

```js
<ul>
   {
      names.map(item => {
         return <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
      })
   }
</ul>
```

and rendered html:

```
<li>John</li>     // id is 100
<li>Anne</li>     // id is 101
<li>Michael</li>  // id is 102
//... a lot of items
<li>Tony</li>     // id is 999
```

Now if we click a Reverse button that causes the component's state to be reversed as this.state.names.reverse(), does key={item.id} still help in this case?

My understanding is that since we reverse the source data, the position for each item has changed and will trigger expensive "Reflow" (mentioned in the above article), so even though React knows which item should be moved to a new position, isn't it quicker to create new li nodes and display them in the new sequence directly? If key={item.id} is used by React to differentiate each li node (which takes time to find each node by its id), isn't it a little bit slower, which is against the goal of using key?

It is like you make a mark on each card of new playing cards and then put them back and shuffle them and then try to make it back to its origin order. Why not just get a new deck of playing cards?